# Add search box for getting started search box

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to add a search box for getting started example (Hello, World) on chrom extensions  http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html, I was able to add a search box so I can change the word/s are used to get different thumbnails ("text=hello%20world").

The problem I faced is how to refresh the contents with a new thumbnails, for ex.:

If I want to search for word jerusalem and click go button the contents (thumbnails) will be updated with a new thumbnails for jerusalem

Do I need to use AJAX? Please explain.

Thanx for any help.

====================
I included jquery in popup.html

Inside showPhotos() function I did the following:

```
function showPhotos() {
//Remove previous thumbs if any
for (var i = document.images.length; i-- > 0;) document.body.removeChild(document.images[i]);

var photos = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");
for (var i = 0, photo; photo = photos[i]; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("image");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var span1 = document.createElement("span");

    $(span1).attr('id', 'innerSpan');
    $(span1).attr('style', 'text-align:center;color:#ffffff;');
    $(span1).addClass('tooltip black bottom center w100 slide-up');
    $(span1).html('<i>' + photo.getAttribute("title") + '</i>');

    $(span).addClass('savytip');
    $(span).attr('id', 'outerSpan');

    $(img).attr('src', constructImageURL(photo));

    $(span1).appendTo(span);
    $(img).appendTo(span);

    $(span).appendTo('body');
}}
```

The extension just work for the first time and the go button stop responding, where is the wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is already using AJAX, aka XHR(XMLHttpRequest).
All you need to do is put the request inside a function to be able to call it again later.
Also You'll need to remove the previous thumbs before appending the new ones(see the first line of 'showPhotos' function).

Here's a working example:
**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
</head>
<body onload="search()">
    <input id="query" value="Hello World"><input type="button" value="go" onclick="search()">
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function search() {
    request(document.getElementById('query').value);
    return false;
}

function request(query) {
    window.req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open(
    "GET",
    "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?" +
        "method=flickr.photos.search&" +
        "api_key=90485e931f687a9b9c2a66bf58a3861a&" +
        "text="+encodeURI(query)+"&" +
        "safe_search=1&" +  // 1 is "safe"
        "content_type=1&" +  // 1 is "photos only"
        "sort=relevance&" +  // another good one is "interestingness-desc"
        "per_page=20",
    true);
    req.onload = showPhotos;
    req.send(null);
}

function showPhotos() {
  //Remove previous thumbs if any
  for(var i=document.images.length;i-->0;) document.body.removeChild(document.images[i]);

  var photos = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");
  for (var i = 0, photo; photo = photos[i]; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("image");
    img.src = constructImageURL(photo);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
}

// See: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html
function constructImageURL(photo) {
  return "http://farm" + photo.getAttribute("farm") +
      ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.getAttribute("server") +
      "/" + photo.getAttribute("id") +
      "_" + photo.getAttribute("secret") +
      "_s.jpg";
}
```

**popup.css**

```
body {
  min-width:357px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

img {
  margin:5px;
  border:2px solid black;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}
```

Comment: hello, thank u for ur help, a small problem happened when I click on go button the popup window reload with the same thumbnails even after I change the value of the text field, when I repeat the process again the go button stops submitting and nothing happens...

Comment: Really strange. Here it's is reloading for the first submit and working properly for subsequent submissions and I don't know why.
So I've just removed the form and put the search call on the onclick event.

Comment: hi, if u check above, I have added the code I use inside showPhotos(). I use jQuery 1.6.4, I don't get it why this happen, try to figure out

Comment: Now the <img> tags are no longer children of document.body(You put the images inside a span). So the removeChild is returning a not found error. Since now you using jQuery you can just do that to remove the previous thumbs $('.savytip').remove();

Comment: thank you very much man, that worked perfectly, one last question: why when we first time change the text inside the text field the window reload and display the default text value? how to improve the extension to not doing that.

Comment: I've already fixed this. Update your popup.html with the one in the answer.